# mac os php | laravel | composer ошибки совместимости

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Проблема: я хотел обновить php до версии 8.3 (framework Laravel)
На официальном сайте я посмотрел какие настройки докера нужно поменять, что бы внутри контейнера версия была 8.3 . Поменял, пересобрал образы.
Запустил - работает.
Посмотрел версию пхп в системе mac os - 8.0 , я подумал что старая и решил обновиться. Обновил до 8.3

В итоге, я создал новый проект Laravel и первым делом попытался установить laravel-ide-helper (сейчас это не важно, проблема со всеми модулями, которые я хочу загрузить )

~/DeveloperWeb/problem  composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Mac os:

```
 ~/DeveloperWeb/problem  php -v
PHP 8.1.26 (cli) (built: Nov 21 2023 21:53:48) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.26, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.26, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Внутри контейнера:

```
 ~/DeveloperWeb/problem  sail php -v
PHP 8.2.13 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2023 08:47:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.13, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.3.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2023, by Derick Rethans
```

Пытаюсь установить модуль
~/DeveloperWeb/problem  composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v10.34.2 requires nesbot/carbon ^2.67 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[2.72.0].
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v1.0.0, ..., v1.5.0] require illuminate/support 4.0.x -> found illuminate/support[v4.0.0, ..., v4.0.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v1.5.1, ..., v1.11.6] require illuminate/support 4.x -> found illuminate/support[v4.0.0, ..., v4.2.17] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.3] require illuminate/support 5.0.x -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.33] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.0.4, ..., v2.1.0] require illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.1.41] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.1.1, ..., v2.1.4] require illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.2.45] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.2.0, ..., v2.2.2] require illuminate/support ^5.0,<5.4 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.3.23] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.2.3, ..., v2.3.2] require illuminate/support ^5.0,<5.5 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.4.0, ..., v2.4.1] require illuminate/support ^5.0,<5.6 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.5.44] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.4.2, ..., v2.4.3] require illuminate/support ^5.0,<5.7 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.6.39] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.5.0, ..., v2.5.3] require illuminate/support ^5.5,<5.8 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.7.28] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.6.0, ..., v2.6.2] require illuminate/support ^5.5,<5.9 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.6.3, ..., v2.6.6] require illuminate/support ^5.5|^6 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.6.7, ..., v2.7.0] require illuminate/support ^5.5|^6|^7 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.8.0 requires illuminate/console ^5.5 || ^6 || ^7 -> found illuminate/console[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.8.1, ..., v2.8.2] require illuminate/console ^6 || ^7 || ^8 -> found illuminate/console[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.9.0, ..., v2.11.0] require illuminate/console ^8 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.12.0, ..., v2.12.3] require illuminate/console ^8 || ^9 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - doctrine/dbal[v2.6.0, ..., v2.9.3] require php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/dbal[v2.10.0, ..., 2.10.4] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/dbal[2.11.0, ..., 2.11.3] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v10.34.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.13.0 requires doctrine/dbal ^2.6 || ^3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/dbal[v2.6.0, ..., 2.13.9, 3.0.0, ..., 3.7.2].
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.7.2.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.4.6.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.3.8.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.3.5.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.2.2.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.1.5.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.1.0.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.0.0.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 2.13.9.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 2.13.8.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 2.13.1.
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 2.12.1.
    - nesbot/carbon 2.72.0 requires carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types * -> satisfiable by carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types[3.0.0].
    - Root composer.json requires barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper * -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v1.0.0, ..., v1.11.6, v2.0.0, ..., v2.13.0].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Я пробовал менять версии на mac os от 7.3 до 8.3 результат одинаковый. Я не знаю что мне делать, помогите пожалуйста

UPDATE: ошибка возникает без запущенного контейнера docker через sail. -> Ошибку выдает c учетом версии php on macos

UPDATE: установил версии php от 7.3 до 8.3 переключаюсь между ними и пытаюсь запустить установку - ошибки одного характера

Comment: Так вам нужно обновить версию PHP на хосте, или в контейнере? Не понятно от слова совсем.

Comment: я не знаю, что вызвает эту не совместимость! Если я бы знал , что вызывает ошибку - я бы написал. Когда я обновлял версию пхп на макос - модули которые говорили о не совместимости были разные. Дело в том , что ядро ларавел , разные модули внутри требуют разные версии. Некоторые пишут что максимальная версия 8.0. а Некоторые говорят что для работы нужна версия 8.1 или 8.2

Comment: Версия PHP в докер контейнере не имеет отношения к версии PHP на самой macOS, потому определитесь что конкретно Вам нужно. В Ваших логах которые Вы здесь привели, PHP 8.3 нет и в помине.

Comment: Вы правы. Значит mac os, поставил все версии пхп от 7.3 до 8.3 переключаю версии и пробую установить расширение . Везде ошибки  одного характера

Answer (score 0):

Эту проблему никак не решить установив новые зависимости.
Единственный вариант

```
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper 2.13.0(последняя версия) --ignore-platform-reqs(игнорируем зависимости) -W ( полное название --with-all-dependencies)
```

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Используйте опцию --with-all-dependencies (-W), чтобы разрешить обновление, понижение и удаление пакетов, которые в данный момент заблокированы для определенных версий.